# Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost

Tags: mysql

***Important: **I know there are loads of articles and topics on how to solve this, but none of them work for me because logging DB in works fine.**

ssh `service mysql status` return running but:

```
Oct 10 12:48:04 vim735ac.flexlyserver.net mysqld[2846372]: 2022-10-10 12:48:04 1334 [Warning] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
Oct 10 12:48:07 vim735ac.flexlyserver.net mysqld[2846372]: 2022-10-10 12:48:07 1336 [Warning] Access denied for user 'da_admin'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
Oct 10 12:48:07 vim735ac.flexlyserver.net mysqld[2846372]: 2022-10-10 12:48:07 1337 [Warning] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
Oct 10 12:48:07 vim735ac.flexlyserver.net mysqld[2846372]: 2022-10-10 12:48:07 1338 [Warning] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
Oct 10 12:48:11 vim735ac.flexlyserver.net mysqld[2846372]: 2022-10-10 12:48:11 1341 [Warning] Access denied for user 'da_admin'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
Oct 10 12:48:11 vim735ac.flexlyserver.net mysqld[2846372]: 2022-10-10 12:48:11 1342 [Warning] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
Oct 10 12:48:11 vim735ac.flexlyserver.net mysqld[2846372]: 2022-10-10 12:48:11 1343 [Warning] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
Oct 10 12:48:14 vim735ac.flexlyserver.net mysqld[2846372]: 2022-10-10 12:48:14 1347 [Warning] Access denied for user 'da_admin'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
Oct 10 12:48:14 vim735ac.flexlyserver.net mysqld[2846372]: 2022-10-10 12:48:14 1348 [Warning] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
Oct 10 12:48:14 vim735ac.flexlyserver.net mysqld[2846372]: 2022-10-10 12:48:14 1349 [Warning] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

I check:

```
mysql -u root -p enter password - login working
mysql -u da_admin -p enter_password - login working
```

I try also  flush privilages.

I try also set password again for mysql root and da_admin

I login also to directadmin in section mysql mangament - working correct.

If the password was incorrect, it would be impossible to create the database with the level of directadmin.

What's happening ? Tried restarting mysql and mariadb. This is a problem all the time. I also turned off the firewall.

Comment: It's not that you're credentials are not working, this is probably some agent running in your server that's trying to connect, so you should look for something like that (maybe watchdog). This is not a MySQL issue per se

Answer (score 0):

I'm not clear on what does or does not work for you.  This is what happens when I use the wrong password:

```
$ mysql -u root -p
Enter password: 
ERROR 1698 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'
```

Line 1 says user root, and asks to prompt for the password.

Note the difference between

```
$ mysql -u root -p foo
$ mysql -u root -pfoo
```

With the space, it will prompt for a password; if that succeeds, it will try to connect to database named `foo`.

Without the space, it will use `foo` as the password.  If that succeeds it will not set the "default database"; I should do `USE ...` next (if I will be looking at data in some database).

I would expect this to give a "usage" error since it does not allow 2 "default databases":

```
$ mysql -u root   -p   enter   password
```